# error when doing setup install on clean database magento2

Tags: magento2, database, setup, sequence

Here is an error that occurs when I run setup:install command on clean database magento2

SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'clean.core_confi
g_data' doesn't exist

I added sequence

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="DevAll_Patches" >
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Config"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

For my DataPatches but still couldn't fix an issue. what can be the problem?

Comment: Confirm this table is available into the database : core_config_data

Comment: If the issue comes from your custom module just try to disable it until the base setup has been made.

Answer (score 0):

According to your error message, it seems that you Magento have installed but some database schema queries didn't get executed. Please check your database for the 'core_config_data' table. If not there create it manually or reinstall Magento2.

Comment: somewhere in the new code  SET AREA CODE was used , that was the problem. thanks for the answer.